# Laravel 8 401 Unauthorized

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I'm using Laravel 8 and sometimes when I access a page (the page doesn't matter) I get the 401 Unauthorized error. But if I reload the error disappears.

If anyone knows or has any idea why this error appears from time to time on any page,
That would help me a lot

Thanks

---

The route:

```
 Route::get('/{client}/user/{id}', 'UserController@getUser')->name('get_user');
```

Comment: Did you login? Do you really sure that you are in the same page? Maybe there can be some query string at the end of your url? Can you provide more information?

Comment: Try running `php artisan config:cache` I can't explain why, but this fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Yes, I log in to enter. I'm browsing and suddenly when I open a page the error appears. I don't know what more information to provide…because it is in general, not in a particular case….

Comment: let us to see your action code for the route.

Comment: are you using Apache or artisan serve ? do you implement policies, roles ...?